# review paper and authorship of ex supervisor

Tags: publications

I am now in another lab now, different from my PhD studies, as a post doc.

We had a review paper in which we included a figure from my thesis, without analyzed or even concentrate the paper to this figure, since it is very common. This figure was included in one of the 10+ topics discussed in this review. Should the authors include the supervisor of my ex-laboratory, as author or could just declare the laboratory and the name of my ex- supervisor to the acknowledgments, where they could thank him personally, as well as his laboratory? (my ex supervisor has not contributed in writing of the review).

Comment: You should list what field you are working in, because this is [very field dependent](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/644/66). In areas like mathematics it is completely unheard of to even consider putting someone's name on a paper that they contributed nothing to.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that only citing him would be enough. My field is cognitive neuroscience, yours might have different rules. I was in the opposite situation, a figure from one of my papers was included in a review where my supervisor was one of the authors. When they described the figure they cited my paper. A citation is quite a nice thing to have, especially in a review.