# Can two PhD students publish without involving their supervisors?

Tags: phd, publications, ethics, authorship

I am a theoretical computer science PhD student. My childhood friend (my present roommate) is in the 3rd year of his pure mathematics PhD program. Very recently we both worked on a problem on combinatorial geometry and got some interesting results to publish. However both of our dissertation topics are way different from this work, so we don't want to involve our advisors in this matter. This was kind of our joint fun project. 
We don't know whether it's academically unethical to publish paper(s) as PhD students without including our advisor(s).

(Note: We have nothing to lose even if they reject our paper right away, but we don't want the editor of the journal to mail the chair about this matter. Maybe I'm thinking too much because I've never done this kind of thing before.)

Comment: This question makes me all kinds of sad.  How do students become so afraid of their advisors that they don't want to brag to them about doing the one thing that PhD students are supposed to do—become independent researchers?

Comment: Maybe the question title should be something like "Can two PhD students publish without involving their supervisors?"

Comment: @JeffE, I wish all supervisors had that much positive attitude about their students that you imagine. I witnessed a supervisor (who NEVER EVER helped her RA) terminated her RA because he had published a very ordinary text in a paid non-ISI journal without supervisor name (not because he did not seek supervisor permission!, but because not put her name!!!). Can you imagine that? Your "Independent researchers" phrase is somehow strange to me. I am thinking, how many percent of the world PhD students have helpful supervisors not misleading students for their own experiment?

Comment: _I witnessed a supervisor...terminated her RA_ — Good.  She needed a new advisor.

Comment: Here is a [related question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/644/66) that might help.

Comment: This question is _especially_ sad coming from a theoretical computer scientist.

Comment: @JeffE The only grad. student I had officially was forced by me to publish his PhD thesis without my name (to avoid the "yeah, I guess that was ...'s work!" atitude, which was far from the truth though I do not claim that my contribution was zero). However, my attitudes are known to be non-orthodox and I know many people for whom it is more important how much and where to publish than what to publish. So, next time you are on FAC, try to fight the ubiquitous practice of giving points for publications (especially with taking journal into account) and linking the score to salary raises.

Comment: @fedja What is FAC?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha Faculty Advisory Committee (this is the most usual name for it in the USA though at some places it is called differently. It is in charge of establishing the main department policies, among other things. The usual "governing trinity" in the department is the chairman, the FAC, and the general department meeting. The exact portion of power held by each varies from place to place.

Comment: @JeffE OP says that they don't *want* to involve their advisors, not that they are afraid of them. It sounds to me that they are simply reluctant to share the credits.

Comment: I concur with @JeffE that something must be really wrong with these advisors that their graduate students are so intimidated. At the very minimum, any advisor worth his salt should discuss rudimentary stuff in the publication like who has to be included in the list of authors on a paper submission.

Comment: You might want to be a little careful about this if you used resources provided by your advisor, then you should involve him.

Comment: @JeffE I have seen that in many of your comments you mention that the person may have to look for a new advisor. Is it normal that a PhD or MSc student change his advisor even in his 3rd year of study when PhD program seems to go to finish? In most of the universities of have seen, students have to talk and choose their advisor in the first month of their PhD program and they are not allowed to change their idea at all. Logically, it is not a good idea to change the thesis advisor at the middle of the way. (If it is not broad or subjective, I can post this question.)

Comment: _Is it normal that a PhD or MSc student change his advisor even in his 3rd year of study_ — Yes, this is completely normal, although relatively rare.  I personally know several former students who changed advisors in their 3rd or 4th year who finished their PhDs and now hold tenure-track faculty positions.  For many of those students, I was the advisor they left.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is nothing unethical about publishing something like what you suggest. Personally I would be happy and encourage a student of mine if that happened. So from a formal side you need not to worry. I can add that authorship, or contributorship, does not include adding names to a paper if they have not contributed anything (or enough; see posts on authorship on this, Academia.sx, site). I would, however, be open about it with your advisor. I assume you have a good working relationship with him/her? The only thing that could complicate things would be if you are in a bad working relationship with your advisor or if your system is very hierarchical and not open to initiatives. Clearly only you can assess this. But, I do not want you to over-emphasize these "risks". If you get stuff published on your own and in a field that is not directly within your topic, it will only be viewed as  a positive in your resume when applying for, for example, post-doctoral positions.

As for risking rejection, I suggest you have someone whose views you trust to read and comment on the paper. Having someone independent look at the work is always good to work out details that can otherwise distract reviewers. This is always a good idea so it is not unique to your case.

Comment: @precision: "see posts on authorship on this, Academia.sx, site)". For example http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/644/285

Comment: @Peter Jansson, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have a good working relationship with my advisor and he is a nice guy. Recently we submitted our work in a peer reviewed journal. The only thing is, he wants me to think always on my dissertation and doesn't like to get distracted by other stuffs.

Comment: _he wants me to think always on my dissertation and doesn't like to get distracted by other stuffs_ — This is a good sign that he thinks you're not making sufficient progress on your thesis to justify your working on other stuff.  Listen to him.  Independence is good, but you must also finish your thesis.  (Ideally, these two goals reinforce each other rather than interfering.)

Comment: @jeffE, Thanks for your suggestion. I have experienced when I work with different groups on different problems,I make good progress on my dissertation . So I believe research students should have some academic freedom and this will help them to see a single problem from different perspectives.

Answer (score 20):

The answer is "yes", but many advisors may respond differently to this. I think it depends much more on the advisor than on any established "academic norm":

- Advisor might not be happy that you are using up your time for "trivial pursuits" on the advisor's grant money when you should be doing "real work toward your thesis". (For the record, I would consider this as a bad reason to be unhappy with your students). Often, if you can ensure that the side project doesn't take up that much time, you can mitigate this risk a little.
- Advisor might be happy that you are independently pursuing projects.
- Advisor might not want a part of this paper simply because of lack of time/energy but otherwise be happy that you're doing it. This is pretty common, for example, in the case of class projects in which you end up with something that's actually pretty significant and the class professor would like you to help publish it.
- Advisor might not want you to "spread yourself out too thin" later in your PhD career. I've been advised to be careful about coming up and getting involved with too many "one-shot" ideas that will never get developed and don't help your overall image. So, for example, if you're in the area of "program analysis and testing" (for example), publishing a one-off paper in a venue (maybe "distributed computing") that you don't keep up with and won't be remembered in will result in a forgettable, low-impact paper. I think this is more of a risk when students are thinking "of things to work on" and aren't really focused or don't have a good idea of a research thread to develop. This is also more of a risk if your academic profile isn't very focused. For example, if you have a bunch of disconnected topics you're more in danger than if you have only one or two side projects in a whole field of papers on your main interest.

  - As a note beneath this one, I think most advisors are mostly concerned that their students are "too distracted". It's easy to do that as a Ph.D ("I can explore anything I want!") - so advisors by nature of their jobs need to make sure that the thesis ends up having focus. Having ideas is a good thing, but putting those ideas into papers is a lot of work. Just to help put a bit of perspective here.

I am generally in favor though of at least letting your advisor know of "side projects" that you're involved in, even class projects, because often they will want to find ways of integrating that into some research work that you can be doing. A good advisor might see a connection between your combinatorial geometry "side project" and your main thesis research, for instance. It's also a good idea, in general, to have a tiny amount of breadth across one or more areas as well. It not only generates good ideas, but helps you keep perspective.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than repeat what others have mentioned in their answers, I'd rather touch upon another related issue:

*In some cases not involving your supervisor also means not involving the institute that you are part of.*

Apart from the issue of attribution, depending on the specifics this may have legal ramifications, especially if you are receiving funds from a grant. Theoretically, if you have used any resources supplied by your institute, including existing ideas, computing power or your own paid work hours, you may not have sole ownership of the resulting IP. Things may get even more complicated if your co-author is colaborating with a different entity.

You may not need to do anything, you may need to get a waiver of IP rights from your institute or you may have to add something along the lines of a *"This work was supported by..."* snippet. If I were you, I would discuss this with my supervisor, even if only to clarify any such issues...

Answer (score 8):

The answer is **Yes**, because I did this, and was actively encouraged to do so.

Your supervisor does not own you. If you did some outside work, and you think it's publishable, and your supervisor wasn't involved, the work wasn't building off their lab's work or using their equipment, there's no reason they need to be involved.

Now, you might *want* to involve them, to get their input, keep them aware of other things you are doing so they can say nice things about the terribly clever projects their students are up to, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Is your advisor supporting you, e.g. as an RA?  If so, he might be perturbed that you are spending time and energy on something "way different" from what you are paid to do.  Along the same lines, he may also be intent on your completion of your degree program in a timely manner so that he can free up resources, say for another student to enter the group after you graduate.

Answer (score 5):

I published a few papers in my area and outside this area, while doing my PhD - without my supervisor's name on them.

In the articles in my research area, one was done with some hints from my supervisor and I gave it to him for review (once it was written), with his name as a co-author. He stroke out his name from it and told me

> Do not let your work be diluted by adding people because "this is expected". I have my share of papers and do not need one more. You will need this one, and it is your work - not mine.

As you can imagine, after that the "thank you" section sounded like I was announcing our engagement.

In other cases (whether in my field or not), when I was the one thinking it out (or working with otherwise unrelated friends), I/we published under our names without asking anyone.

As a side note - one of the reasons I left the academic world (which is per se wonderful and I have fantastic memories) is the feudal relationship I witnessed, together with the idea that people are slave to "recommendation letters". This is certainly a specific case but do not let yourself, at that stage, become obsessed with political correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, by all means.

The thing you both need to discuss with respectively supervisors is the time you spent on this, and convince them that this will not adversely affect your "proper" work with them.