# What might the editor do if my supervisor contacts a journal to claim authorship of a paper?

Tags: phd, publications, ethics, authorship, editors

When I was doing my PhD project, I got an idea to solve a different but related problem. However, my supervisor said neither the motivation nor the initial result were interesting, and so he refused to offer me help on this topic. Then, I did a paper on my own with a lot of work afterwards, and submitted it to a high standard journal, and it was accepted.

My supervisor knew this, and he commanded me to add his name to the paper, otherwise he would write to the editor. I asked him what his contribution was. He had nothing to say, but insisted he had spent time to discuss the result with me.

So, if he writes to the editor, what would happen? Or if the paper has been published, then he has nothing to do with it? I am pretty much sure he can almost show nothing about the evidence of the contribution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Should I put my supervisor as coauthor of a paper?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20631/should-i-put-my-supervisor-as-coauthor-of-a-paper/20637#20637)

Comment: In fact, I am more interested in what the editor will do with this situation

Comment: For reference, in the question aeismail mentioned, the next step was [a formal allegation of misconduct](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21710/how-to-respond-to-allegations-of-misconduct-in-authorship-dispute)

Comment: Your question about the relationship with your supervisor is a separate question from what the editor might do. Separate questions in the same problem domain should be asked in a new post.

Comment: Answers to these two questions may also help you. [How/when to become independent in research as a graduate student?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24170/how-when-to-become-independent-in-research-as-a-graduate-student) and [Advisor's/University's rights in the PhD/MSc alumni's research projects and publications](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24297/advisors-universitys-rights-in-the-phd-msc-alumnis-research-projects-and-publ).

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to the main question: Do you have emails or other written material verifying your claims that the professor indeed initially was not interested in the problem, or otherwise would indicate that he might have given up on his claim to authorship? Similarly, are there any emails implying that you might have asked for guidance from the supervisor?

Comment: "Or if the paper has been published, then he has nothing to do with it?" Not sure what this sentence means.

Comment: In other words, if the paper is under review, it is very likely that the editor would withdraw the paper if he receives a letter claiming the authorship.

Comment: "He had nothing to say, but insisted he had spent time to discuss the result with me". A warning -- this appears confused. Did he have nothing to say, or did he say something you disagreed with (that he contributed by discussing the result with you)? You need to be absolutely clear what "contribution" means in your field before you can begin to assert that your supervisor didn't do it. If running the lab as PI is seen by the editor as a contribution to every paper that comes out of the lab, that's going to inform their actions.

Comment: He said as long as it was part of the PhD thesis, the supervisor had the right for the authorship. He threatened to report it to the ethics board of the department, but he did nothing.

Answer (score 16):

The short answer is that the editor will likely ask for more information from you and the adviser in response to a letter such as your adviser apparently plan to write. I doubt any action will be taken immediately and without some research if the editor is taking the task seriously.

As an editor, I would find this sort of case very difficult since I would (most likely) receive two conflicting pictures of the story. Editors have the power to take whatever action they find appropriate. Their decisions may of course be disputed and the story could go on. In a case that is relatively similar in parts ([case link](http://publicationethics.org/case/authorship-issue)), an editor has turned to the [Committee on Publication ethics](http://publicationethics.org/) to get support in a decision. Their case portfolio can also be of help to editors.

Obviously, following the linked case, an editor will try to have you and your adviser fix the problem yourself, it is after all primarily your problem. Hopefully the editor will come up with a plan for further actions, perhaps, as in the case, bring in a mediator and finally, if all fails, make a decision based on the existing facts that will be final. Some similar line of action seems appropriate and was also deemed appropriate by COPE. What route an editor will take may of course differ depending on the case but the aim will be to try to resolve what is right or wrong will be the aim and if all fails a suggestion on how the journal will proceed will follow.

Comment: COPE has a series of flowcharts on how to handle the most common issues : http://publicationethics.org/resources/flowcharts .  See specifically the 'if you suspect ghost, guest or gift authorship' chart and the page on 'how to spot authorship problems', and maybe the 'ethical problem' chart

Answer (score 4):

Further to Ben's comment: I'd say that your advisor has burned bridges with you, which is unfortunate.  There is a lesson in this for doctoral students.  Choosing an advisor is a life-altering decision.  Personal compatibility and reputation are as important as professional reputation.

The filial obligations run in both directions: whatever you do in your field will reflect in some degree on your advisor.  It's in your advisor's interest to help you along professionally.  It is unfortunate that your advisor has chosen to take this sort of action.  He (She?) apparently wants the hit in an "A" journal.

What can the editor do?  Anything she wants to do, actually.  You don't say if the paper is in print yet.  The best case for you is that it is not in print yet.  Adding your advisor as co-author is still possible, and this whole mess can remain relatively closely held to you, your advisor and the editor.  If the paper has appeared already, the editor could do anything from withdrawing the paper (very bad, as that action reeks of plagiarism or other academic dishonesty) to issuing a corrigendum note (not as bad as withdrawing the paper, but bad).  In the short run, the best case for you would be for the editor to do nothing.  I'm not sure that is in your long-run best interest, however.

What should you do?  Someone has to be the bigger, better person.  Your advisor has already (to the extent that your version of the story reflects the actual history) revealed him(her?)self to be a rather petty person.  I'd say to add your advisor as co-author.  The power dynamics are pretty asymmetric here and you are on the weak side.  Unless you care to go to your University's research ethics system with a complaint (and you'd better have irrefutable proof the situation is precisely as you say if you choose this route) and ruin your advisor's career, there isn't much you can do.  Whistleblowers often do not fare well.

Comment: To me this is awful advise. You should not put someone as a coauthor of your paper to "be the bigger person". Publishing a paper with non-contributing authors is also misconduct by those contributing authors who let it happen.

Comment: The case is far from as clear-cut as you suggest.  Picking one's battles is important, and I see enough gray in this that it is a battle worth avoiding.  If the case is **exactly** as presented, then maybe it's a battle worth fighting.  Maybe.  When I look at the upside and downside risks, I'm not certain.  To expand a bit, we do not know what form the "negative comments" took.  If they were detailed comments about why it was not interesting and what would be interesting, then perhaps the advisor feels a substantive contribution was made.

Comment: I fail to see any gray area here. The way this has been described, the advisor is as close to having made a negative contribution to this paper as is possible.