# Should the Advisors and PIs always be a coauthor?

Tags: publications, advisor, authorship

I am collaborating with another person on a paper and I was wondering if we are suppose to write our advisor's name in our papers merely because they funded us and looked over the paper?

Comment: An even more direct duplicate of [When should a supervisor be an author?][1]


  [1]: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/644/when-should-a-supervisor-be-an-author