# When to add a coauthor to a paper I am working on?

Tags: etiquette, authorship

I am doing a phd in computer science.

Months ago, I was having an informal discussion about my research topic with my advisor, and he came out with a very high level conjecture about my research topic, something like "I have the feeling that A implies B".

Now, I am working with other people on a different project, and during the work for this paper, I realized that what we were doing demonstrated that the conjecture of my advisor was correct (so A do implies B), and this makes a lot stronger our paper.

Now, which is the right etiquette to follow in terms of authorship of the paper?

- Should I ask my advisor to join the project as a coauthor because the paper proves what he informally conjectured?
- Should I simply speak to him notifying this fact and add him in the acknowledgement?

I have a great relation with him, but I am not sure on how to behave with respect to this topic.

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/644/when-should-a-supervisor-be-an-author

Comment: I would always just ask the person involved, this prevents you from offending the person in case you do not add him as a co-author. Furthermore, it allows your advisor to say if he feels that his contribution does not warrant a co-authorship, while staying on friendly terms with said person.

Answer (score 2):

First, **yes, you should speak with him**. There different ways how to approach him and I would suggest to inform him about your progress (something you should do anyway) and to just **ask him how to proceed** regarding co-authorship.

In general, merely posing a conjecture does not merit co-authorship, but you could ask, if he would like to contribute to the paper (e.g. by checking/rewriting the proof/statement of the conjecture, providing more intuition as to why this conjecture is true, putting the conjecture in context with references…).

Comment: Sometimes posing a conjecture is actually what gives the student the whole direction, without which he or she would be unable to progress, hence making such contributions essential and merit of coauthorship

Comment: @Dirk Regarding your second paragraph, it is worth taking into account the idiosyncrasies of the field. In *Theoretical* CS (not sure if the OP is referring to CS or TCS), for instance: (i) the authors are alphabetical, so no concept of first/second author; (ii) papers typically have relatively few authors (2-3 usually, >5 is exceptional); (iii) asking the "right" question, or formulating the "right" conjecture is very often grounds for authorship (well, some papers actually are *all* about phrasing things the right way or coming up with the right view).

Comment: Yes, I know. Fields and subfields vary, posing a conjecture may be trivial or crucial,.... This is why I wrote a quite general answer: 1. Discuss the situation. 2. Nothing is obviously clear in this situation.